# C pointer anomaly, please explain

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc, malloc

I have a function, the basic idea of the function is to change what `a` points to. The first version works however the second version does not.

Could someone please help me to understand what is going on here?

```
// this works
void swap(int **a) {
    int *temp = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    temp[0] = 0;
    temp[1] = 1;
    temp[2] = 2;
    *a = temp;
}

// this does not
void swap(int **a) {
    *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    *a[0] = 0;
    *a[1] = 1; // seg fault occurs on this line
    *a[2] = 2;
}
```

I am calling the function like so

```
int main() {
   int b[] = {0,1};
   int *a = b;

   swap(&a);

   return 0;
}
```

Also, both functions do not belong to the same file at the same time.

Comment: You are doing something very wrong in the second function.

Comment: Why naming a new variable with same name of the paramater?

Comment: re declaring the int array in the second swap function was an oversight when posting here. I have removed it from the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The precedence of `[]` is higher than `*` (in fact, `[]` has the highest precedence in C).  That means your expression is `*(a[0])` rather than `(*a)[0]` as you intended.

Comment: I'm not sure `(*a)[0]` was intended, as `*a` is not subscriptable.

Comment: Thanks Ben, that did the trick, also thanks for the included explanation.